# Apache .htaccess compare 2 variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables

I'm trying to compare the value of 2 variables in the htaccess file and throw a 403 if they do not match, and it needs to be a nested if.

Nested if appears to be possible but I can't find anything that says you cannot compare 2 variables in an if statement. Does anyone know if this is valid or possible? Is there a better way to do this in the htaccess file?

Thank you.

```
RewriteEngine On
<If "%{ENV:LOAD_BALANCER_MODE} == '1'">
    <If "%{HTTP:X-LOAD-BALANCER} != %{ENV:LOAD_BALANCER_KEY}">
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    </If>
</If>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem has to do with running Apache on version 2.4.25 - that's the default debian stretch comes with. Nested if is not available until 2.4.26 as stated here: [apache 2.4, nested If directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137409/apache-2-4-nested-if-directives).

If you are trying to do something similar, use one if with && - the following does exactly what the above does and works with Apache 2.4.25:

```
RewriteEngine On
<If "%{ENV:LOAD_BALANCER_MODE} == '1' && %{HTTP:X-LOAD-BALANCER} != %{ENV:LOAD_BALANCER_KEY}">
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</If>
```